# preg_match either of two different (but somewhat similar) string patterns?

Tags: php, regex, switch-statement, preg-match

I'm looping through an PHP array of file names to build a select list of files matching two different patterns.

I have it working on one or the other pattern, but not both at the same time:

```
    foreach ($file_array as $file_link) {
    $p = '~(-([a-z]{2})\.pdf(|(-([a-z]{4})\.pdf)~';
    preg_match($p, $file_link, $matches);
    switch ($matches[1]) {
        case 'en':
            $link_array[1] = array('English', $file_link);
            break;
        case 'ja':
            $link_array[2] = array('日本語', $file_link);
            break;
        ...
        case 'ptbr':
            $link_array[13] = array('Português brasileiro', $file_link);
            break;
        case 'ptpt':
            $link_array[14] = array('Português europeu', $file_link);
            break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The files in the $file_array are in the formats:

- file-name-en.pdf
- file-name-ja.pdf
- file-name-ptbr.pdf
- file-name-ptpt.pdf

I'm hoping to match on either the `-([a-z]{2})\.pdf` or `-([a-z]{4})\.pdf` patterns. What am I missing in the above `$p = '~(-([a-z]{2})\.pdf(|(-([a-z]{4})\.pdf)~';` to get this working.

Moreover, is there a better way to go about this short of changing the file names to another format (which I'm trying to avoid)?

My client actually wants the files in this format, but it seems even more troublesome:

- file-name-pt-br.pdf
- file-name-pt-pt.pdf

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex with additional check in the form of a non-capturing group `(?:-[a-z]{2})?` that will capture `pt-br`:

```
 `-([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?|[a-z]{4})\.pdf`

 $p = "~-([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?|[a-z]{4})\.pdf~";
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB3lX8/4).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a single regular expression, try something like the following (pardon the `%` bounding characters, different from your `~`.  The `x` modifier used to allow comments

```
$regex = '%
-                            # starting -
(                            # start grouping parenthesis 
    [a-z]{2}                 #     a through z repeated twice
    |                        #     or
    [a-z]{4}                 #     a through z repeated four times
)                            # end group
\.pdf$                       # string ends in .pdf
%x';
```

Also, while regular expressions are always a fun exercise, don't be afraid to use a single regex for each pattern.  While there's a theoretical performance hit, chances are it won't impact your application.  Similarly, don't be afraid of eschewing regular expressions for some simpler explode/implodes

```
$parts      = explode('.', $filename);
$extension  = array_pop($parts);
$full       = implode('',  $parts);  
$parts      = explode('-', $full);

$identifier = array_pop($parts);

switch($identifier)
{
    case 'en':
        break;
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Alan. That may be a useful approach in the future. I had thought about doing something like that, but it looks like @stribizhev answer above does exactly what I need.